# Is there an option to execute javascript file only on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom plugin for WordPress and I'm trying to execute `javascript` file only once right after plugin activations.

I'm using `register_activation_hook()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue file only once when the plugin is activated.

There are no errors in the code since the `javascript` code works well if it is called outside the `register_activation_hook()`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'full_install' );
function full_install() {
    function rest_api() {
        wp_enqueue_script('activation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/activation_data_api.js', __FILE__));
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rest_api' );
}
```

In the end, the plugin needs to execute `javascript` file only once right after activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'rest_api_hook' );

/**
 * Runs only when the plugin is activated.
 */
function rest_api_hook() {

    /* Create data */
    set_transient( 'rest_api', true, 5 );
}

/* Add notice */
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'rest_api_hook_exec' );

/**
 * Rest API Notice on Activation.
 */
function rest_api_hook_exec() {

    /* Check transient, if is available display notice */
    if( get_transient( 'rest_api' ) ) { 

        // Execute script
        wp_enqueue_script('activation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/activation_data_api.js', __FILE__));

        // Delete script after executing
        delete_transient( 'rest_api' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use option variable to render your code only one time if plugin activated. Check below

```
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'full_install' );
    function full_install() {
        add_option('xxx_plugin_activated', 'true');
    }

    if(get_option('xxx_plugin_activated')) {
        function rest_api() {
            wp_enqueue_script('activation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/activation_data_api.js', __FILE__));
            delete_option('xxx_plugin_activated');
        }
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rest_api' );
    }
```

Comment: @upss1988  "no it's not working" is fine for end-user but you are a dev, please put more information into it.

Comment: @human There is no information since there is no error. I suppose that the code calls `javascript`, but not execute it. I try to execute that specific `javascript` file only once after plugin activation.

Comment: maybe option deleted before rendering the activation js file. I have updated the code, can you please try again.

Comment: @PramodKumar, unfortunately, it won't work. thanks for the try.